Why do I get merge conflicts when rebasing onto an empty commit with `rebase-merges`?
We're transferring an old repository and as part of that we want to make a review of all existing code. The first commit is not empty, so we created a new root commit on main that is empty so that we can review all code. All the code to review is in review branch.
To do this, we want to rebase all changes in review ontop of the new, empty commit in main. This is done with git rebase --rebase-merges=rebase-cousins main.
However, we end up with merge conflicts that need to be resolved, which is weird, given --rebase-merges?
If we don't specify rebase-cousins there are no merge conflicts, but its not rebased either - main and review still has two separate roots.
I tried training "rerere" with ./train-rerere.sh <first commit SHA>..HEAD, but that didn't seem to affect anything.
I've also set rerere.enabled = true.
So, my questions is: why do I get merge conflicts when rebasing ontop of an empty commit, with --rebase-merges?

Rebasing onto an empty commit is always a mess.

Rebasing onto an empty commit means that there are no prior changes in that commit to resolve against. If the changes in your review branch are significant or if they depend on the context of previous commits, Git may struggle to apply them cleanly, resulting in conflicts.
Use git rebase -i to manually resolve conflicts and reorder commits as needed.
If preserving the history is not critical, you can merge the review branch into the main branch instead of rebasing.

I guess my confusion is why does git struggle to apply the changes? The only thing I'm trying to do is to insert an empty commit, one that does not modify anything, before all the others. It already has all the answers in the history, and I don't see how any change would conflict with an empty commit? We'll, eventually merge, but we need to set up a PR/MR, that's why we need it on a separate branch to begin with. We also want to preserve history, so no squashing.

git-rebase(1) uses the diffs of the commits that you are replaying (in the
vernacular) to create new commits.  Those diffs rely on you applying (basing)
them on a context where they fit.
The context of an empty commit in the sense that there is nothing—no files at
all, no content—is that you can apply fresh files all you want.  Like:
diff --git a/salutations.txt b/salutations.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..18249f3
--- /dev/null
+++ b/salutations.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+Hello world.

This is a new file.  This applies to an empty tree [1] just fine.
But this one does not:
diff --git a/salutations.txt b/salutations.txt
index dba1a16..714ba46 100644
--- a/salutations.txt
+++ b/salutations.txt
@@ -1 +1,3 @@
+Hello world.
+
 Goodbye world...

Here the line without a + (added) or a - (removed) prefix (just a space) is
a context line.  The diff says to add “Hello world.” to the first line, a
blank line to the second line, and that “Goodbye world” is an existing line.  So
you’ll get a merge conflict if you try to apply the diff to an empty tree.
Reason being that the context line is missing.
With all of that said.  I don’t see any reason for you to rebase commits on
empty trees in order to review them.  Reviewing commits in terms of commits
doesn’t force you to move them anywhere.  Or, well I don’t see how it helps.
Notes

An empty tree is a directory tree without any files.  This is what you start
out with after git init


Sorry, I don't quite understand. The commit history that we have contains the complete history of the directory. The only thing missing in the history is an empty initial commit. (We need the empty commit first, or the diff between the branches would exclude any files added in the first commit) So why would the suddenly occur a merge conflict at commit #900 (or so)? I can't tell for sure, but I would guess there were merge conflicts prior to that. We want to move them because we want to preserve history. We won't go through it commit-by-commit, but file-by-file instead.
